# Rails migration returning index too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

Below is the migration file I have defined to rename the column in schooling_document_types_managing_areas table but the issue is when I run the migration I am getting an error Index name is too long; the limit is 63 characters. Then I tried, something like

`rename_column :schooling_document_types_managing_areas, :service_id, :managing_area_id, name: :index_schooling_documents_on_managing_area`

then it returns

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3).

Any idea where I am going wrong

```
class RenameColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    rename_column :schooling_document_types_managing_areas, :service_id, :managing_area_id
  end

  def down
    rename_column :schooling_document_types_managing_areas, :managing_area_id, :service_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about removing the index and re-adding it?

```
def change
  remove_index :schooling_document_types_managing_areas, name: :index_schooling_document_types_managing_areas_on_service_id
  rename_column :schooling_document_types_managing_areas, :service_id, :managing_area_id
  add_index :schooling_document_types_managing_areas, name: :index_schooling_documents_on_managing_area
end
```

Also, I'm not sure about the nature of your data in production for that `service_id` field, but keep in mind that just renaming [isn't the safest way](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations#renaming-a-column) in case there are people using your app in the very exact moment that you're running your migration.